# How to get the client id with ct100$

Tags: postback, clientid

This is the extension to my previously asked question. I think I am not getting an answer. So I am describing it again.

I have this button inside radajaxpanel. I want to postback and I am am using the javascript code. Everything works fine

```
      <asp:Button ID="btnSave"  runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="OnBtnExcel_Click" OnClientClick="PostBack(); return false;" />

rendered as
     <input type="button" name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$MainContent$btnSave" value="Save" onclick="PostBack(); return false;__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$MainContent$btnSave','')" id="MainContent_MainContent_MainContent_btnSave">
```

I am hard coding the id of button as 'ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$MainContent$btnSave' in the code below. is there a way to capture this ?

```
 function PostBack() {

                $find("<%= RadAjaxPanelFilter.ClientID %>").__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$MainContent$btnSave', '');
            }
```

Comment: For future reference, if you're clarifying an existing question, such as in response to comments, it is sometimes better to click "edit" on the original question rather than creating a new one with no history.

Comment: The string you need is rendered into the HTML `name` attribute, so I think it ought to be accessible as `this.name` or similar (can't test, so not posting as an answer).

Comment: this.id does not render a string with $ sign.

Comment: this.id does not render a string with $ sign but a _.  ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_MainContent_MainContent_btnSave this is when I have clientIDMode="AutoID"

Comment: `name` is not the same as `id`

Comment: great!!! this.name gives me ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$MainContent$btnSave...thanks mate